# Void* arithmetic and type casting

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers

I have tried to understand `void*` recently by testing a few things, here is the test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float nb2 = 2.2;
    void* multi_type_ptr = &nb2;

    printf("\nmulti_type_ptr:\n");
    printf("Elem 1: %f\n",*(float*)multi_type_ptr);

    // *(multi_type_ptr + 1) = 4;

    // *(int*)(multi_type_ptr + 1) = 4;

    *((int*)multi_type_ptr + 1) = 4;

    printf("Elem 2: %d\n",*((int*)multi_type_ptr + 1));

    return 0;
}
```

Does this instruction can't work because the language/compiler don't know how much bytes it should add to the address of `multi_type_ptr` (it doesn't know the size of the type pointed by `void*`)?

```
*(multi_type_ptr + 1) = 4;
```

Also a `void*` cannot be dereferenced, so it should be cast to the right type, right?
 *This line still can't work because of the issue mentioned above.*

```
*(int*)(multi_type_ptr + 1) = 4;
```

Does this assignment works because the language/compiler understand it have to add `(1 * sizeof int)` to the address `of multi_type_ptr`? *I use cl compiler included in Visual Studio*.

```
*((int*)multi_type_ptr + 1) = 4;
```

It looks like the result of `(multi_type_ptr + 1)` is still an `(int*)` when its content is accessed by the `*` at the beginning of the line, am i right?
Thank you in advance for your future correction, explanation and reinforcement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several questions here:

> Does this instruction can't work because the language/compiler dont know how much bytes it should add to the adress of multi_type_ptr (it doesn't know the size of the type pointed by void*)?

```
*(multi_type_ptr + 1) = 4;
```

Yes, you are right. Some compilers (GCC for example) allow pointer arithmetic with `void` pointers and treat them as if pointing to objects of size 1 (just like `char*`), to avoid the frequent cast from `void*` just to move around.

> Does this assignment works bacause the language/compiler understand it have to add (1 * sizeof int) to the adress of multi_type_ptr? I use cl compiler included in Visual Studio.

```
*((int*)multi_type_ptr + 1) = 4;
```

Yes, right again. But note that while this code is syntactically correct, and it will compile, it is technically Undefined Behaviour for two reasons:

1. You are *type punning* or *type aliasing* the `nb2` variable. That is you are accessing it using a different type than that defined (defined as `float`, used as `int`) (the exception would be that you are using `char` pointers, but that is not the case).
2. If `2*sizeof(int) > sizeof(float)` (quite likely) then your pointer arithmetic is taking you outside of `nb2` bounds, and you are probably corrupting your stack.

> It looks like the result of (multi_type_ptr + 1) is still an (int*) when its content is accessed by the * at the begginning of the line, am i right?

No. Cast operator have high precedence, so this line:

```
*((int*)multi_type_ptr + 1) = 4;
```

is actually read as:

```
*(((int*)multi_type_ptr) + 1) = 4;
```

That is, like:

```
int *temp1 = (int*)multi_type_ptr);
int *temp2 = t1 + 1;
*temp2 = 4;
```

But again, beware the *type aliasing*!

Comment: You should also mention that this causes additional UB if the the `float` type isn't big enough to hold two `int` values.

Comment: "That is you are accessing it using a different type than that defined (defined as float, used as int).". What if i do `*(int*)((float*)multi_type_ptr + 1) = 4;` , will it still cause undefined behavior?

Comment: @Barmar: Well, yes. But since you already have UB because of the type punning without considering type sizes, and technically you cannot have two UBs, that point is technically moot. However, in practice, the type punning UB is unlikely to have side effects, while the type size UB will likely crash your program!

Comment: @aurelienC: That would be just the same, you are accessing memory defined as `float` while dereferencing an `int*`.

Comment: @rodrigo : Hum thanks, there is still a lot of things i am not sure of, but that's enough for this question.

Answer (score 3):

```
*(multi_type_ptr + 1) = 4;
```

The expression `multi_type_ptr + 1` is not valid C because C does not allow pointer arithmetic with `void *`.

```
*((int*)multi_type_ptr + 1) = 4;
```

This statement compiles in your machine because  `(int*) multi_type_ptr + 1` does pointer arithmetic with `int *`. Nevertheless pointer addition in C is undefined behavior if the resulting pointer is not in the same array object as the operand (or one past the last element) and dereferencing the resulting pointer is undefined behavior if the resulting pointer is outside the array object, so in your case the `*` expression (and thus the statement) invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Nitpicking: Computing a pointer one past an array is fine, too, as long as you don't dereference it.

Comment: If `2*sizeof(int) <= sizeof(float)` then he's not accessing outside the object.

Comment: @Barmar that's the right, but even in this case it is also UB because of aliasing violation.

Comment: That's true, but it's not what you said. rodrigo's answer goes into more detail about that.